# Add long version to glossary acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

Is it possible to show the long form of an acronym in the glossary display ?

I have a lot of acronyms, and the end of document display only shows the short version.

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}

%Packages utilisés

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym
    [description={riggity raggity}]
    {bop}{BOP}{Breathing Out Parents}    
 
\newacronym
    [description={music style}]
    {rnb}{RNB}{Rythm N' Blues}   
    
\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}

Blabla \gls{bop} and \gls{rnb}. But \gls{rnb} is better.

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Gives :
[image: MWE image]

I would like the entries to also display the long format. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a little bit to late, but perhaps anyone could need this as an inspiration of one way to go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym[description={riggity raggity}]{bop}{BOP}{Breathing Out Parents}    
\newacronym[description={music style}]{rnb}{RNB}{Rythm N' Blues}   

\newglossarystyle{yourStyle}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{p{.15\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%                   setting the table's header
        \bfseries  & \bfseries Meaning & \bfseries Description
        \\\tabularnewline\endhead}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%              no heading between groups
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%                    main entries displayed 
        \textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}% name
        & \glsentrylong{##1}%                           meaning
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}%                         description
        \tabularnewline%                                end of row
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%                    no distance between groups
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    Blabla \gls{bop} and \gls{rnb}. But \gls{rnb} is better.
    
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=yourStyle]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice, I wish I had that earlier, I'll just have to use it next time round ! Thanks :)

Comment: How would you adjust the style definition to still include page numbers where the acronyms are used?

Comment: Do you mean on a general note (if so, I would refer to this [gallery](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery) and just select one which would suits you) or do you mean how to add the page number(s) as a 4h column within above solution?