# Glossaries: print acronym followed by expansion and description

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Apologies if this is covered in the manual, but the `glossaries` package is very expansive and I cannot seem to find this anywhere.

I am trying to use a single glossary for all items and acronyms, with descriptions. I followed the guides for [mixed glossaries](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=mixed-glossary)
and [abbreviations with descriptions](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=acronym-desc) and arrived at something like:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronymlists={main}]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype,%
  description={fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi}]% description
  {ndl}% key
  {NDL}% acronym
  {nam dui ligula}% long form

\setglossarysection{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Hello \gls{ndl}!

\section{Conclusions}
Goodbye \gls{ndl}!

\printglossary[style=list]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: long-short-desc]

This is fine, and I prefer the long-short-desc style for in-text usage. However, I would like to have the acronyms printed **first** in the actual glossary, like:

**NDL** nam dui lingula, description

or

**NDL (nam dui lingula)** description

This is for a couple of reasons, the primary being sorting. For example, the acronym for the amino acid asparagine is the letter N, and so I would like the acronym to be explained under N and not A in the glossary. I am not particularly bothered about the formatting like brackets or emphasis at this point.

However, I am completely lost as to how I would do it. Switching to `\setacronymstyle{short-long-desc}` changes the order in-text (which I do not want), but keeps the order in the glossary (which I wanted to change):

[image: short-long-desc]

Finally, I thought I might just forget about the descriptions, and just generate the list per [the mixed glossary](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=mixed-glossary), as this seems to at least have the right order (minus the descriptions). To my surprise, switching to `\setacronymstyle{long-short}` removes the long acronym name instead of the description!

[image: long-short]

What next? Can I achieve what I want? And if not, do I need to manually remove the description from each item to go back to a basic acronym list?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all and because you already said it yourself: `\setacronymstyle` is for in-text-usage (so stick to your preferred _long-short-desc_ choice) and not for the `\printglossary` command. There you control the output via the `style` option (which you choose as _list_). You may try different styles - examples can be found at [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/).

Comment: Right. Would you happen to know how can I modify the glossary style to fit my needs?

Comment: Therefore i would be good to know more about what you are trying to accomplish by merging acronyms and every other glossary entry. Because it's much more simpler to modify / fit a style for one category only. So ... any chance for separate glossaries?Or to ask in a different way: why a mixed glossary in the first place?

Comment: The reason was primarily that I had mostly acronyms with just a couple of non-acronym glossary items and I thought it was silly to create separate sections for them.

However I am not sure if the source of the problem is in mixing the glossary with the acronyms. I did some fiddling around an no matter which glossary style I use, or if I use \printacronyms or \printglossary, or what acronym style I use, the only way I could get the acronym printed first was when I manually deleted the descriptions from the acronym definitions.

Comment: Which I would prefer to avoid, since I already wrote a file full of descriptions... I would be willing to let them go if it was possible by switching a package option rather than deleting them.

Comment: In this case perhaps [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560275/add-long-version-to-glossary-acronyms/565077#565077) of mine for a similar question could be of use?